A problem occurred configuring project ':mcumgr_flutter'
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':mcumgr_flutter'.


'other' has different root


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
